# React Native: One Signal push notification set state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onesignal, setstate

I have installed the [OneSignal package](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) on my react native application and want to insert the notification to my state so the notification is accessable within to class.

So, I tried to do this so far:

```
import OneSignal from "react-native-onesignal";

export default class SuperScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPopup: false,
      pushNotification: null
    };

    OneSignal.init("<mykey>", {kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true});
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);

    OneSignal.addEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
}

onOpened(openResult) {
    console.log("Message: ", openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log("Data: ", openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log("isActive: ", openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log("openResult: ", openResult);

    this.setState({ pushNotification: openResult});
}
```

But I always get `this.setState(...)` is not a function. So I added modified the line to this:

`this.setState({ pushNotification: openResult}).bind(this);`

However, I still get the same result.. I just want to update the state. Can you guys explain me why I am getting this error message and how can I fix it?

Kind regards and Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is happening because `onOpened` is not bound to the class component so the value of `this` inside `onOpened`is not the one you expect (it's just `null`).

In order to fix it you can use class properties + an arrow function

```
onOpened = (openResult) => {
    console.log("Message: ", openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log("Data: ", openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log("isActive: ", openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log("openResult: ", openResult);

    this.setState({ pushNotification: openResult});
}
```

or you can bind it in the constructor using `.bind(this)`

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPopup: false,
      pushNotification: null
    };

    this.onOpened = this.onOpened.bind(this); // <--- here

    OneSignal.init("<mykey>", {kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true});
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);

    OneSignal.addEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
}
```